# Include Underscore.js with jQuery no-conflict

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I need to include underscore.js in a platform that primarily  uses  Prototype.js and has jQuery in noconflict mode.

How do we do it? Backbone for example shows that we can point to jQuery using Backbone.$ = $j.

But underscorejs.org doesn't seem to have any information around it.

Thanks,

Comment: I had the impression that underscore works with jQuery out of the box. Not sure though.

Comment: What's wrong with using Underscore, did you use `_ = jQuery.noConflict()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special for this if you have both Backbone and jQuery (in no-conflict mode or not) on the page.

Here is the part of the Backbone code (as of Backbone 0.9.10) where Backbone.$ is assigned:

```
Backbone.$ = root.jQuery || root.Zepto || root.ender;
```

What this means is that Backbone.$ will get set to use the "jQuery" variable if it exists (and it should whether you're in noConflict mode or not), and if it isn't there it will try to use Zepto or ender libraries instead.

Source:
https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/21a875b2c50b8a69760b4e6a80495a153e5065b3/backbone.js#L44

If you're asking specifically about Underscore and jQuery, please be aware that Underscore has no dependency on jQuery at all -- it is only Backbone that has a dependency on it (or one of the other libraries mentioned).